# Changing Bilingual JTextArea Font

Tags: fonts, jtextarea

I am making a simple java chat app. I want to know if
there is any possibility to change the font of a JTextArea when language is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to add a change listener to the text area to listen to the language change and setting the font using [setFont](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29)

Comment: I'm not sure. I just want the text be displayed correctly

Comment: You can use the setFont method to set the font for a JTextArea. Do you have any sample code for this?

Comment: I know that but when the language is changed it just displays rectangle instead of characters